Insert contents of a vector into another vector at certain offest
Without context, here is the basic question: I want to insert the contents of a std::vector<uint8_t> a {0, 3, 6, 8} into a std::vector<uint8_t b {0, 3, 6} in a way so that it results into the vector {0, 3, 6, 8}.
And here is a bit more context to my specific situation:
There is a std::vector<uint8_t> called data_file_data. I want to fill this vector with the data of different files, which I do in a for loop:
for (const FileSection &file_section : dict->file_array)
        RepackFile(data_file_data, file_section);

FileSection is a struct containing important information on the file I want to repack, like its offset in data_file_data.
Here is the function that repacks files:
void DictDataManager::RepackFile(std::vector<uint8_t> &data_file_data, const FileSection &file_section)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> file_data;
    uint32_t file_data_size = is_compressed ? file_section.compressed_file_length : file_section.decompressed_file_length;
    file_data.resize(file_data_size);

    std::ifstream extracted_file(file_section.file_path);
    extracted_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(file_data.data()), file_data_size);
    extracted_file.close();

    if (is_compressed)
        file_data = CompressDataBuffer(file_data, file_section.compressed_file_length);
    
    // What now?
}

The problem is, for example, that I have two files that start at offset 0, but one file has 37956 bytes and the other one has 53856 bytes. The data for both is the same in the first 37956 bytes, so I would be able to overwrite the data in data_file_data without problems after already inserting the data of the first file, and now wanting to insert the data of the second file.
I have been trying to use the insert() function in this manner data_file_data.insert(data_file_data.begin()+file_section.offset, file_data.begin(), file_data.end());, but unfortunately this doesn't overwrite any data, but well, just inserts it, which gives me a significantly larger vector than expected and doesn't reconstruct the original file of course.
So what simple alternative do I have to really just write data from a certain offset, and at the same time also have the vector dynamically allocate a new size, like insert() would do it?

It would be clearer if you removed DictDataManager, FileSection etc. from the question, and simply asked about std::vector<uint8_t> operations. Let's say you have: v1 = {1, 2, 3} (small file), and v2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} (big file). Do you want simply to have v_out = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ?

I formulated it like this do prevent possible solutions that might come up and aren't feasible in my situation.
But yes, what you wrote with the vector operations is what I meant. I'll add it to my question to maybe make it a bit clearer :)

The offset is specific to the data_file_data vector, so if I use it on the file_data vector it might even result in an out of scope operation.

Your description is ambiguous.  What is the logic by which you expect "inserting"  a = {0, 3, 6, 8} into b = {0, 3, 6} gives result = {0, 3, 6, 8}?   There are many possible ways produce to results you describe in that example, such as "start with b, then append any elements of a that are not in b",   "produce a sorted vector containing every value in either a or b", and many other possibilities.  Each possibility will be coded differently, would produce the required result for your single example, but will produce different results for different examples of a and b.

@Peter just thought the same. The easiest implementation is to not do anything. Test is green. Get a coffee. :)

You .resize() the vector to the correct size manually, then std::copy() or std::memcpy() the bytes.
It might be a good idea to compute the final size once at the beginning, to avoid reallocating several times.
Also a possible optimization is using std::unique_ptr and std::make_unique_for_overwrite() to avoid zeroing the memory.

This is a bit inconvenient, as the final size is quite troublesome to calculate. But as long as there are no better solutions, I think this will be sufficient enough, so thank you :)

@Schweini Why is it troublesome? Isn't it just the max of offset[i] + size[i] across all fragments? Or if there's no easy way to list fragments in advance, you could resize on every iteration, before copying bytes.

You are completely correct! That just flew over my head. That's quite a nice solution now, thanks!
